# openssl s_client:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl, handshake

I'm trying to connect to SSL server from linux but it does not work.
I need to auth by a client certificate from a Windows client http (C# httpwebrequest) but it does not work.

So I have tried using an internal reverse proxy with Linux/Apache (it does the  client authentifcation) but it does not work. Here is the configuration :

```
<VirtualHost host:443>
 ServerName host:443

 # SRV SSL
 SSLEngine On
 SSLCertificateFile /cert.cer
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /cert.key

 # REVERSE PROXY
 SSLProxyEngine On
 ProxyPass / https://host:443/
 ProxyPassReverse / https://host:443/
 ProxyRequests Off

 SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
 SSLProxyCheckPeerName off

 # AUTHENTIFICATION CERT CLIENT (concat crt et key SANS pwd)
 SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile "/cert.crt.key"

 # Log Dev
 TransferLog logs/test.ssl_access_log
 ErrorLog logs/test.ssl_error_log

# DEBUG
  <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    ErrorLog logs/ssl_engine.log
    LogLevel debug
  </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

And here is the ssl_engine.log :

```
[Sat Mar 03 18:23:06.813995 2018] [proxy:debug] [pid 5892] proxy_util.c(2798): AH02824: HTTPS: connection established with xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 (host)
[Sat Mar 03 18:23:06.814011 2018] [proxy:debug] [pid 5892] proxy_util.c(2938): AH00962: HTTPS: connection complete to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 (host)
[Sat Mar 03 18:23:06.814015 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 5892] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] AH01964: Connection to child 0 established (server localhost:443)
[Sat Mar 03 18:23:06.844164 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 5892] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] AH02003: SSL Proxy connect failed
[Sat Mar 03 18:23:06.844212 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 5892] SSL Library Error: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
[Sat Mar 03 18:23:06.844219 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 5892] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] AH01998: Connection closed to child 0 with abortive shutdown (server localhost:443)
[Sat Mar 03 18:23:06.844234 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 5892] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] AH01997: SSL handshake failed: sending 502
[Sat Mar 03 18:23:06.844250 2018] [proxy_http:error] [pid 5892] (103)Software caused connection abort: [client 172.20.6.150:56860] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server host:443
[Sat Mar 03 18:23:06.844275 2018] [proxy_http:debug] [pid 5892] mod_proxy_http.c(1363): [client 172.20.6.150:56860] AH01105: NOT Closing connection to client although reading from backend server host:443 failed.
[Sat Mar 03 18:23:06.844280 2018] [proxy:error] [pid 5892] [client 172.20.6.150:56860] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /recette/tib/depotGreffe/C0002A0121L091616D20180129H100031TDEDOCPCFEC.zip
[Sat Mar 03 18:23:06.844292 2018] [proxy:debug] [pid 5892] proxy_util.c(2218): AH00943: HTTPS: has released connection for (host)
[Sat Mar 03 18:23:06.844483 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 5892] [client 172.20.6.150:56860] AH01992: SSL library error 1 reading data
[Sat Mar 03 18:23:06.844497 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 5892] SSL Library Error: error:140E0197:SSL routines:SSL_shutdown:shutdown while in init
[Sat Mar 03 18:23:07.054533 2018] [proxy:debug] [pid 5893] proxy_util.c(1843): AH00925: initializing worker https://host/ shared
[Sat Mar 03 18:23:07.054583 2018] [proxy:debug] [pid 5893] proxy_util.c(1885): AH00927: initializing worker https://host/ local
[Sat Mar 03 18:23:07.054597 2018] [proxy:debug] [pid 5893] proxy_util.c(1936): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 5893 for (host)
[Sat Mar 03 18:23:11.849565 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 5892] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 172.20.6.150:56860] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
[Sat Mar 03 18:23:11.849662 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 5892] ssl_engine_io.c(993): [client 172.20.6.150:56860] AH02001: Connection closed to child 4 with standard shutdown (server localhost:443)
[Sat Mar 03 18:23:52.003050 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 5888] [client 172.20.7.77:53311] AH01964: Connection to child 0 established (server localhost:443)
[Sat Mar 03 18:23:52.019141 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 5888] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1823): [client 172.20.7.77:53311] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
[Sat Mar 03 18:23:52.019411 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 5888] ssl_engine_io.c(993): [client 172.20.7.77:53311] AH02001: Connection closed to child 0 with standard shutdown (server localhost:443)
[Sat Mar 03 18:24:52.001523 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 5889] [client 172.20.7.77:53884] AH01964: Connection to child 1 established (server localhost:443)
[Sat Mar 03 18:24:52.016324 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 5889] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1823): [client 172.20.7.77:53884] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
[Sat Mar 03 18:24:52.018222 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 5889] ssl_engine_io.c(993): [client 172.20.7.77:53884] AH02001: Connection closed to child 1 with standard shutdown (server localhost:443)
[Sat Mar 03 18:25:52.000848 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 5890] [client 172.20.7.77:54435] AH01964: Connection to child 2 established (server localhost:443)
[Sat Mar 03 18:25:52.018430 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 5890] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1823): [client 172.20.7.77:54435] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
[Sat Mar 03 18:25:52.018656 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 5890] ssl_engine_io.c(993): [client 172.20.7.77:54435] AH02001: Connection closed to child 2 with standard shutdown (server localhost:443)
```

I have tried many tests with curl but nothing (with client auth options) :

```
curl -v -k --cert /cert.crt.key https://host/path

* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* NSS error -12286 (SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP)
* Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).
```

I have dump trafic using tcpdump and analyse it with ssldump and I have a handshake failure (only client hello but non server hello) :

```
ssldump -nr /trace.cap
New TCP connection #1: 172.20.7.85(44122) <-> xxx.xxx.111.106(443)
1 1  0.1201 (0.1201)  C>S  Handshake
      ClientHello
        Version 3.3
        cipher suites
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        Unknown value 0xcca9
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        Unknown value 0xcca8
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        Unknown value 0xccaa
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
        compression methods
                  NULL
1 2  0.1507 (0.0305)  S>C  Alert
    level           fatal
    value           handshake_failure
1    0.1508 (0.0000)  C>S  TCP FIN
1    0.1803 (0.0294)  S>C  TCP FIN
```

It seems I have never the "server hello" from the server and so never have server cipher.

I'm trying with openssl client like this :

```
openssl s_client -connect host:443 -cert /mycert.pem -key /mycert.key -debug -state

SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
read from 0xc48060 [0xc7dc00] (7 bytes => 7 (0x7))
0000 - 15 03 01 00 02 02 28                              ......(
SSL3 alert read:fatal:handshake failure
SSL_connect:error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
140342855083936:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:769:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 289 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1520095823
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

I have also tried with wget :

```
wget -v -d --secure-protocol=TLSv1 --no-check-certificate --certificate=/cert.pem --private-key=/cert.key https://host
URI encoding = «UTF-8»
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x0000000002538850 (new refcount 1).
Initiating SSL handshake.
SSL handshake failed.
OpenSSL: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
Closed fd 3
Incapable d'établir une connexion SSL.
```

Files are pem b64 format and not encryption password.

I have added CA autority certificate from both remote ssl server and client authentificate certificate (intranet CA) in ca-bundle (redhat).

**It seems to work with Internet Explorer (using only tls1.0) !!**

Anyone can help me ? Is certificate (ssl server or auth client) can be the problem or not (because it handshake stop after 'client hello') ?

I'm going to tried with fiddler like a proxy https server from Windows IE...

Thank you

Comment: curl --version
curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 NSS/3.28.4 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.4.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz unix-sockets

Comment: openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) md2(int) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx)

Comment: Since you don't even get a ServerHello it is not related to the client certificate. Since it works with TLS 1.0 on IE but not with others you should analyze the TLS handshake from IE and try to reproduce it with the other clients (i.e. ciphers, TLS version..). I suspect that there is some old and broken server using obsolete and insecure ciphers and maybe is TLS version intolerant. But, it is impossible to know based on your information. And it is impossible to find out more since there is no way to reproduce the issue for others.

Comment: All of your tests show that the server is not working (except this strange TLS 1.0 with IE), check your server configuration particularly the SSL part.

Comment: Please don't spam tags for every command that you happen to have run while troubleshooting.